# SQL case based on input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to be able to select two different results of data from a table based on the input string. So far I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM
wherever WHERE
AND 1 = case @Series 
                when '% SA %' then 
                    case when Cttn.CttnNme LIKE '%ALL SA%'
                    then 1 else 0 
                end 
                else
                    case when Cttn.CttnNme LIKE Isnull(@Series, Cttn.CttnNme) 
                    then 1 else 0
                end 
         END
```

However it's never seeming to hit the `when '% SA %' then` part.

Could anyone please show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards aren't supported in a CASE..WHEN. Use and/or logic instead.

```
WHERE
   (
      (
          @Series like '% SA %' and
          Cttn.CttnName like '%ALL SA%'
      )
      OR
      Cttn.CttnNme LIKE Isnull(@Series, Cttn.CttnNme)
   )
   AND
   ...
```

Comment: This actually works really well ! One question: I have quite a few `AND`s - should I put them all before this `and or` ?

Comment: Glad it's working. I modified the answer to show where you should add the other conditions.